# How to serialize a class from an external file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

In the application I am developing, I need to load some classes from an external file using CSharpScript and (de)serialize the content into a csv string using XMLSerialization. When i try to serialize i get this error: "Identifier 'Submission#0' is not CSL-Compliant".

I created the same class inside my project use the same exact code and it works perfectly.
The class I am trying to (de)serialize looks like this:

```cs
[Serializable()]
public class PlantData : IPlantData
{
    public short Index { get; set; }

    public int ItemID
    {
        get
        {
            return item_data_?.ID ?? 0;
        }
    }

    public DATA_ELEMENT_SOURCE Source { get; set; }

    private IPlantItemData item_data_;
    public object ItemData
    {
        get => item_data_;
        set
        {
            if (value is IPlantItemData data)
                item_data_ = data;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to serialize the class, obj is the class and types is the explict types to use for conversion.

```cs
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), types);
```

While debugging i have checked that obj.GetType() returns one if the types i passed in 'types'

I tried to google and searched on here but I only found questions related to Azure projects, which don't work in my case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `Submission#0` and how does it relate to this code? does it at all? it is very hard to understand the question without that context... (also, minor note: don't add `[Serializable]` - it doesn't have any impact here)

Comment: As I said, i am loading the class from an external file using CSharpScript and compiling at runtime, I don't have any reference to the class itself in the code, I can only get its type and the class is defined as Sumbission#0.PlantData

Comment: not sure how you want us to comment on it then, really... but I agree with the compiler: `Submission#0` is not a valid name in C#